# To use keytool, should I add the embedded jdk from android studio to the PATH or should I install jdk globally?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running **MacOS** and installed **Android Studio**. Android development goes well until I need to run `keytool` command.

```
$ keytool 
No Java runtime present, requesting install.

$ which keytool
/usr/bin/keytool

$ ls -l /usr/bin/keytool 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  77 Jul 26 15:47 /usr/bin/keytool -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/keytool

$ pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/keytool 
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/keytool

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Core
pkg-version: 10.13.6.1.1.1530695593
install-time: 1532586646
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755

$ ls /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool 
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
```

I found out `Android Studio` is actually using its embedded jdk for development which is located at `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/`. My question is:
Should I add this to my `PATH` var in `.bash_profile` or should I install jdk globally to use `keytool`? What is the recommended way to handle this? I don't do any other java development except android.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody replied me, I just added my answer. I just added the embedded jdk path to PATH var in `~/.bash_profile` such as:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin:${PATH}"
```

So far, it's working fine.

Comment: I have the same probkem, but i don't have .bash_profile file. What is it and where can i get it?